# iptables configuration not working

Tags: linux, iptables, redhat

I have a VPS for Apples push notification service I am trying to open a port 2195. I am currently doing this

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

then I go to insert mode of vi and enter these two lines

```
-A -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 2195 -j ACCEPT
-A -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 2195 -j ACCEPT
```

then I save the file and quit vi.

Then I restart iptables service by

```
service iptables restart.
```

But after that when I try to telnet by doing

```
 telnet localhost 2195
```

I get this

Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused

Any pointers....?

Server is red hat on hostgator

Comment: Could you add the output of `iptables -L -n -v` ?  The policy of each chain and any other rules will be important in answering this question.

Comment: Try telnet your_ip 2195 and see if in this way is working. Where your_ip is the real ip not 127.0.0.1 .

Answer (score 4):

Your rules are bad. You can't use -A and -I together, -A means append as last rule, -I menas insert as first rule.

Comment: Good spot.  I didn't even notice that.  I just jumped straight to the port bit.

Answer (score 1):

Two things I notice immediately:

1. You have allowed packets out with a **destination** port of 2195 but if someone contacts your server on 2195 then your return packets will have a **source** port of 2195.  Depending on what traffic is needed, you can either change the `--dport` in the OUTPUT chain to `--sport` or add two extra rules with `--sport` as well.
2. A `connection refused` error implies different things about what has happened to the connection than a timeout would.  It suggests that your service is not listening on port 2195.  Could you run `netstat -tan | grep LISTEN` and check that your service is listening on port 2195 on the loopback interface?

Answer (score 0):

Please first validate your rules are applied or not via

```
sudo iptables -L -vnx
```

If the rules is there, make sure the service which listens on 2195 is running or not.

```
sudo netstat -tulpn
```